# How to display even numbers between 2 inputs AND depending if num1 > num2 and vice versa

Tags: java, while-loop

I have a question that asks to get a user to input two numbers. You then have to print the even numbers between those two numbers... if the first number is smaller than the second then the even numbers will print small to large. if the first number is larger then they print largest to smallest. I am SO confused and my code shows that ...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab605{ //create for loops to find given output. 
   public static void main(String[] args){

   int num1, num2;
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.print("Please type a number: "); 
   num1 = keyboard.nextInt();
   System.out.print("Enter another number: ");
   num2 = keyboard.nextInt();

   int i = 0;
   while ( i <= num1){
      if(num1 < num2){
         if(i%2 == 0){
         System.out.print("The even numbers between " + num1 + " and    " + num2+ " are: " + i);
      i++;
      }
      }
    }
   }
}
```

Can someone please help guide me through how to properly do this? Also need to use a while loop for it!

Comment: We aren't here to do your homework for you. We will answer direct questions. This is not a direct question.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int num1, num2;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please type a number: ");
    num1 = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter another number: ");
    num2 = keyboard.nextInt();
    int i = 0;
    int l, s;
    boolean upToDown = false;
    if (num1 > num2) {
        l = num1;
        s = num2;
        upToDown = true;
    } else {
        l = num2;
        s = num1;
    }

    if (upToDown) {
        i = l % 2 == 0 ? l : l - 1;

        while (i - s > 0) {
            System.out.println(i - 2);
            i = i - 2;
        }
    } else {
        i = s % 2 == 0 ? s : s + 1;

        while (l - i > 0) {
            System.out.println(i + 2);
            i = i + 2;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below code, I have added comments. I think you can understand,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab605 { // create for loops to find given output.
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int num1, num2;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please type a number: ");
        num1 = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter another number: ");
        num2 = keyboard.nextInt();

        int smallNum = 0; // Identify small number
        int largeNum = 0; // Identify large number
        boolean isNum1Large = false;
        if (num1 - num2 > 0) {
            smallNum = num2;
            largeNum = num1;
            isNum1Large = true;
        } else {
            smallNum = num1;
            largeNum = num2;
        }

        if (isNum1Large) { //If first number is large
            for (int i = largeNum - 1; i > smallNum; i--) {
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }
        } else { //If first number is small
            for (int i = smallNum + 1; i < largeNum; i++) {
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```